# Eclipse shows only te function selected in outline

Tags: eclipse, ide, hidden, outline

Maybe I've broke some stuff in settings or something like this but Eclipse starts to show in editor ONLY the function/method that chosen in outline pane. No other code showing in editor. Unchecking "Link with editor" was not helpful. Once thing is helping is reopening of file. But once clicking something in Outline pane all code except chosen function disappearing again so Outline becomes quite useless pane.

Does somebody knows where I could turn off such behavior to make it acting as it was - just jumping to selected function but not hide other code.

Thanks in advance! And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everybody for posting so silly question. However, maybe it would be helpful for somebody to know - just found why Eclipse was acting like I've described.

Settings->Javascript->Editor->Only show the selected element. Uncheck this.

Don't even know why it needs such strange settings option...

Thanks again!